# How to create a plot area polygon geometry into multiple plot area polygon geometry using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, mapproxy

I am using Mapnik, Mapproxy and OpenLayers 6 for the development of GIS based web-application. Now I need to divide the selected polygon area(land plot)into multiple as per user requirement using the GIS web application. The user want to divide the polygon plot area  into multiple along with textual information  by selecting in the GIS map How to develop the polygon splitting features as shaded in the attached picture?

[image]

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site require that existing code is included in the question. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code, otherwise question is most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please explain also wath do you mean by "I need to split". Is this interactively or programmatically on the basis of given coordinates?